# es6 import for side effects meaning

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6

I was reading the es6 import statement [reference on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import). The syntax:

```
import "my-module";
```

will import an entire module for side effects only, without importing any bindings. I am not sure what **side effects** mean. I have been using with **angular** by saying `import "angular"`. Angular binds to window but does not return a object. So I am not sure if this would be called as a side effect exactly.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

When you need to import something that doesn't export anything, but does something else, this is a side effect only module. You import it only to initialize it.

**Pure and Non Pure Modules**

If you think about modules as functions, a module that only effects the scope by exporting it's content is like a function that always returns the same thing (a pure function without parameters). No matter how many times you'll import react 15.01, you'll always get an object that contains the same methods.

A module with side-effects is one that changes the scope in other ways then returning something, and it's effects are not always predictable, and can be affected by outside forces (non pure function). A polyfill for example, might not do anything, because it finds that the feature that it enables is already supported by the browser.

**Examples of side effects:**

- Angular binds to the global `window` object, but doesn't export
  anything.
- A polyfill that enables ES6 features in the browsers that don't
  support them, like [babel polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/) is a side effect.
- Many jQuery plugins attach themselves to the global jQuery object.
- Analytics modules that run in the background, monitor user interaction, and send the data to a server.
- Importing CSS in webpack can be considered a side effect if you're not using CSS modules.

Answer (score 27):

Here is an example:

```
//a.js
export function print1()
{
  console.log("export print1 is working");
}

function print2()
{
  console.log("non-export print2 is working");
}

print1();
print2();

//b.js
import "a.js";
```

When you run "b.js", you will see the printed messages, which are called `side effects`.

Comment: If you make multiple calls to the same side-effect, will it be triggered twice?

Comment: @FilipSeman: the modules are only *evaluated **once***, so multiple calls will have no effect. `print1()` and `print2()` will only be called once even with multiple imports of same file :)

Answer (score 4):

Consider Below as a example code. 
as you try to import something , it wouldn't export anything but do many things and overrides you existing code(if you have) so that's the side effect.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
Ember.RSVP.configure('onerror', function(error) {
    ....
});
```

**app.js:**

```
import './overrides/extra';
```