# Angular 10 Stricter Settings --strict

Tags: angular, angular-cli

In Angular 10 you can create a new project using `ng new --strict`

> Enabling this flag initializes your new project with a few new
> settings that improve maintainability, help you catch bugs ahead of
> time, and allow the CLI to perform advanced optimizations on your app

Is there a command line that will upgrade an existing project to strict mode, or I just need to create a new project and then copy-paste the files from the other project?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Basically a couple things change:

1. `tsconfig.base.json` gets some new rules:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "strict": true,
  "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
  "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
},
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "strictInjectionParameters": true,
  "strictTemplates": true
}
```

2. the `tslint.json` gets updated

```
"no-any": true
```

3. the bundle budget sizes are reduced in your `angular.json`:

```
"configurations": {
  //...
  [envName]: {
    "budgets": [
      {
        "type": "initial",
        "maximumWarning": "500kb",
        "maximumError": "1mb",
      },
      {
        "type": "anyComponentStyle",
        "maximumWarning": "2kb",
        "maximumError": "4kb",
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

and a schematics addition to your `projects.[projectName].schematics` path in the `angular.json`:

```
schematics: {
  "@schematics/angular:application": {
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

4. the app `package.json` gets updated with a `sideEffects` property:

```
sideEffects: false
```

For an explanation what this does, I can refer you to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49203452/3106920) answer.

This `package.json` is located inside your app folder. It should be added there with the migration while using the `ng update` option. If you do not have this file, you can use this [template](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/schematics/angular/application/other-files/package.json.template)

To convert a current codebase, especially the tsconfig updates and the `no-any` will give you some headache to fix. But it will be definitely worth it to get a better (less hidden bugs) and easier to refactor codebase.

Comment: so,no migration for existing code? we have to change this manually? and is this all?

Comment: @thReality You will have to migrate your existing code manually. Because they are basically possible 'bugs', which all need manual updating. This cannot be automated. And yes, this is "all". It may not look like much, but like i mentioned, the tsconfig update and the no-any have a big impact

Comment: I am more interested in the following line `Configures your app as side-effect free to enable more advanced tree-shaking`. How exactly is this achieved and how can I enable it in the existing project?

Comment: @BlindDespair I did some more digging, and found a couple more changes.

Comment: @PoulKruijt Great answer! could you fix the typo in `sideEfects: false`, people are likely to copy paste that.

Comment: I don't have tsconfig.base.json. but I do have tsconfig.app.json and tsconfig.json. are those the same thing?

Comment: @Rick no, with angular 10 the angular team has refactored the tsconfig 'mess' that was first and improved the development experience. If you do not have that file, it means you did not migrate properly by using `ng update`. Read [here](https://volosoft.com/blog/what-is-new-in-angular-10) for more information about what they've updated, and somehow try to run the migration

Comment: I just ng new strict and put new configuration files in my existing code then manually merge some lines, then my app go kaboom with "any" errors lmao :)))))

Comment: any way for a "no-any" rule that just show warning?

Comment: @ar099968 sure, you can update the `tslint.json` and instead of `"no-any": true` you do `"no-any": { "severity": "warning" }`

Comment: the "template" link isn't working anymore

Comment: Can see it in the 10.x branch https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/10.0.x/packages/schematics/angular/application/other-files/package.json.template