# Why side-effect for my node.js code not worked

Tags: javascript, node.js, side-effects

I'm beginner in NodeJS(version v21.6.1) and I tried to implement a code in multiple modules to understand side-effect concept in JavaScript but the code not worked, why?

```
// main.js

import './bootstrap.js';

console.log(` >>>>>>>>>>>>>> ${globalThis.someFunctionDep}`);
//  >>>>>>>>>>>>>> undefined

globalThis.someFunctionDep = true;

import './someModule.js';



// bootstrap.js

export default () => {
    globalThis.someFunctionDep = false;
    console.log("??????????????????");
}




// someModule.js

if (!Object.hasOwn(globalThis, "someFunctionDep") || !globalThis.someFunctionDep) {
    throw 'globalThis.someFunctionDep is not set';
}
```

I desired to automatically exported function in `bootstrap.js` module ran and add global variable `someFunctionDep` to context and accessible by others modules, but currently on the others this value is not available and is `undefined`.

Notice: If you answer is "function on the bootstrap.js file not ran automatically", please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41327002/612124) .

Comment: What didn't work as expected? What were you expecting to occur instead? (Note, you're exporting a function that never gets called, perhaps that is what's confusing you)

Comment: Maybe that's because you have a typo: someFuncitonDep instead of someFunctionDep

Comment: see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41127479/es6-import-for-side-effects-meaning

Comment: no @Kastet6398, only my custom error raising that is related to `globalThis.someFunctionDep` not set and is undefined

Comment: The question updated

Comment: Your `bootstrap.js` file never call the function. And the module that import it never call the function. Just defining a function does not cause the function to execute

Comment: Very developer use JS but major percents haven't correct sense about how this work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I desired to automatically exported function in `bootstrap.js` module ran and add global variable `someFunctionDep` to context and accessible by others modules, but currently on the others this value is not available and is undefined.

The issue is that you never **call** the function you're exporting from `bootstrap.js`. All you've done is export a function. `main.js` (or some other module, or `bootstrap.js` itself) would have to *call* that function to see its side-effects, just like any other function.

You've mentioned [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41327002/157247), saying it conflicts with what I'm saying above, but the difference is that in that answer there's a **call** to the function (`print1` in that case), right there in the module exporting it; notice the `print1();` call below the `print2` function declaration. Your module doesn't have a call to the function, which is why the code in the function doesn't run.

You need to add a call to your function somewhere. It could be in `bootstrap.js` although that would require changing how you export it:

```
function x() {
    globalThis.someFunctionDep = false;
    console.log("??????????????????");
}
x();
export default x;
```

Or it could be in `main.js`:

```
import fn from "./bootstrap.js":
fn();
```

Note that if it's in `main.js`, the call to `fn()` won't happen before `someModule.js` is loaded; see below for details on that.

---

I think you're expecting the imports to happen when the `import` declarations are reached in the code. That isn't how JavaScript modules work. Instead, module dependencies are determined *statically* by looking at all of the `import` and `export` declarations in the interconnected modules, and then modules are loaded and their code executed in the appropriate order for the resulting module graph. *Where* the `import` declarations are in your modules' code relative to the step-by-step code in those modules is irrelevant.

Your `main.js` code is functionally equivalent to:

```
import './bootstrap.js';
import './someModule.js';

console.log(` >>>>>>>>>>>>>> ${globalThis.someFunctionDep}`);
//  >>>>>>>>>>>>>> undefined

globalThis.someFunctionDep = true;
```

...and the top-level code of both `bootstrap.js` and `someModule.js` will execute before the top-level code of `main.js` (because there are no cyclical relationships; it gets more complicated when there are).

Finally: If you want to understand side-effects and module loading, it would probably be simpler just to use `console.log` to show when the top-level code in each module ran. For instance:

`main.js`:

```
import "./mod1.js";
import "./mod2.js";

console.log("main");
```

`mod1.js`:

```
console.log("mod1");
```

`mod2.js`:

```
console.log("mod2");
```

With that, you'll see:

```
mod1
mod2
main
```

Comment: No, this is a practical code, and not about code engineering , this is about determining global variable by concept of side-effect

Comment: @M.javid - Did you see my edit several minutes ago after you edited your question to explain what you were asking?

Comment: I correct my misspelled mistake but output continuously not as expected, In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41127479/es6-import-for-side-effects-meaning post answer of @derek told opposite of you about ran exported function automatically and get very positive votes

Comment: @M.javid - I assume you mean [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41327002/157247). That answer *has a call to the function*, right there in the module; notice the `print1();` call below the `print2` function declaration. Your module *doesn't* have a call to the function, as I pointed out at the top of the answer above, which is why the code in the function doesn't run.

Comment: Yessssssssssssssss, please refer to this part in answer, THANK YOU

Comment: @t-j-crowder One another thing, in main.js after update the variable value and in import of someModule.js, this global variable value is `false` why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256803/discussion-between-m-javid-and-t-j-crowder).

Comment: @M.javid - What does the code you're asking about look like? I don't want to guess at the changes you've made. Perhaps a pastebin.com since this is (probably) tangential to the question.